# Help with Linq to Entities query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I am trying to increase my knowledge of linq so I would like to create the following query without using a stored procedure but I am not really sure how to structure it.

If I have three table/entities:

**Farmer** (FarmerId, BusinessTitle)

**Produce** (ProduceId, ProduceTitle)

**FarmerProduce** (FarmerId, ProduceId)

How would I do a query that searched the BusinessTitle & ProduceTitle for a particular word (say Raspberry) and returned a list of Farmer entities.

I can achieve a search on either Farmer of Produce separately e.g.:

```
var query = (from f in farmer
            where f.BusinessTitle.Contains("raspberry")
            select l).ToList();

var query = (from fp in FarmerProduce
            where fp.Produce.ProduceTitle.Contains("raspberry")
            select fp.Farmer).ToList();
```

But I am unsure how to combine the FarmerProduce "lookup table" into a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the farmers:

```
var query = from f in farmer
            where f.BusinessTitle.Contains("raspberry") 
                  || f.Produces.Any(p => p.ProduceTitle.Contains("raspberry"))
            select f;
```

Assuming the many-to-many was inported as a `Produces`navigation property.

Comment: nice! thanks for the quick response that does the trick. btw I think the f.Produces.Any is meant to be f.FarmerProduce.Any (that's what I had to do to get it to compile)

Answer (score 2):

This one should be a simple OR in linq by the looks of it.

```
var query = (from fp in FarmerProduce
            where fp.Produce.ProduceTitle.Contains("raspberry")
            || fp.Farmer.BusinessTitle.Contains("raspberry")
            select fp.Farmer).Distinct().ToList();
```

Added Distinct.

Comment: lol yes actually this works too, I had a mental blank apparently because this is what I usually do and is the logical answer - sorry I marked the other one as correct but either work. I think because I was modifying an original query using only farmer, I didn't think to swap over to querying on FarmerProduce.